# Bootstrap Wizard next button not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have spent all night trying to debug this code and I have tried a number of things.

First the issue I am having is I am using a bootstrap Admin template and have included a Form wizard to step through sections of the form. I am using ASP.net and a Master Form (That hold the bootstrap menu and navbar.

The issue is as soon as I add the wizard it is not working when I click on the next button. I have used the exact code for the wizard as provided by the template and is as per code below. Still does not work(The template works fine, but is not in ASP.net but instead an HTML file, so not sure if this is an issue).

The rest of the java script on the page works i.e. Navbar collapse and menu expanding.
What I have tried but not limited to:

1. Adding a direct weblink to the wizard JS
2. Rearranging the order of reference to the Java script
3. Removing all controls within the steps and trying as a blank wizard

I am really lost for wards and I have come to the end of every possible option I can think of

Because of the amount of text I can add in this form I have had to add my code to Jfiddle as below links:

This is my ASP.net Webform

jsfiddle.net/Tees101/2vmzLjhv

This is my Master Form

jsfiddle.net/Tees101/s7q4b2ed

Comment: Your fiddles are using asp.net code in the tags, I don't think jsfiddle will render it correctly. Try writing it in pure html without ASP code. Simplify your scenario to the bare minimum and that may help you find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: After clicking next button, what kind of error occur? check out on chrome

Comment: I don't get an error it just does not respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below lines at the bottom of your HTML/Asp.net page, just above closing the body tag `</body>` To solve the issue.

```
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Replace 3.3.0 and 1.11.1 with the proper version which you are using in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not properly arranged.

Master Page should contain all the global .css and .js files those will be used throughout pages. What you are doing is keeping those global file on content page.

Content Page should contain page level html also if required then .css and .js file in head place holder. You are stuffing entire .css and .js to single content page.

You can arrange your code as below so that .css and .js files will load properly and hopefully resolve your wizard not working issue.

Also important thing is to load .js files by resolving the URL with the help of Page.Resolve method

Master Page

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="main.master.vb" Inherits="iconHub.main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

    <!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie ie9" lang="en" class="no-js"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !(IE)]><!-->
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <link href="~/YOUR_PATH/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="~/YOUR_PATH/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="~/YOUR_PATH/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="~/YOUR_PATH/my-custom-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <link href="assets/css/main-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="assets/css/main-ie-part2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="~/YOUR_PATH/ico/kingadmin-favicon144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="~/YOUR_PATH/ico/kingadmin-favicon114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="~/YOUR_PATH/ico/kingadmin-favicon72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="~/YOUR_PATH/ico/kingadmin-favicon57x57.png">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../ico/favicon.png">

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>  
</head>
<body>
    <form id="mainForm" runat="server">

        <!-- navbar -->
        <div style="position: absolute; height: 25px; width: 100%;">
            <div class="top-bar navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <a href="#" class="pull-left toggle-sidebar-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                        <div class="pull-left left logo">
                            <a href="index.html"><img src="~/YOUR_PATH/img/kingadmin-logo-white.png" alt="Admin Dashboard" /></a>
                            <h1 class="sr-only">Admin Dashboard</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-right right">
                            <div class="searchbox">
                                <div id="tour-searchbox" class="input-group">
                                    <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="enter keyword here...">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                                            </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="top-bar-right">
                                <button type="button" id="start-tour" class="btn btn-link"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>Start Tour</button>
                                <button type="button" id="global-volume" class="btn btn-link btn-global-volume"><i class="fa"></i></button>
                                <div class="notifications">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="notification-item inbox">
                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span class="count">2</span>
                                                            <span class="circle"></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                    <li class="notification-header">
                                                        <em>You have 2 unread messages</em>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="inbox-item clearfix">
                                                        <a href="#">
                                                            <div class="media">
                                                                <div class="media-left">
                                                                    <img class="media-object" src="~/YOUR_PATH/img/user1.png" alt="Antonio">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="media-body">
                                                                    <h5 class="media-heading name">Antonius</h5>
                                                                    <p class="text">The problem just happened this morning.</p>
                                                                    <span class="timestamp">4 minutes ago</span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="inbox-item unread clearfix">
                                                        <a href="#">
                                                            <div class="media">
                                                                <div class="media-left">
                                                                    <img class="media-object" src="~/YOUR_PATH/img/user2.png" alt="Antonio">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="media-body">
                                                                    <h5 class="media-heading name">Michael</h5>
                                                                    <p class="text">Hey dude, cool theme!</p>
                                                                    <span class="timestamp">2 hours ago</span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="inbox-item unread clearfix">
                                                        <a href="#">
                                                            <div class="media">
                                                                <div class="media-left">
                                                                    <img class="media-object" src="../img/user3.png" alt="Antonio">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="media-body">
                                                                    <h5 class="media-heading name">Stella</h5>
                                                                    <p class="text">Ok now I can see the status for each item. Thanks! :D</p>
                                                                    <span class="timestamp">Oct 6</span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="inbox-item clearfix">
                                                        <a href="#">
                                                            <div class="media">
                                                                <div class="media-left">
                                                                    <img class="media-object" src="~/YOUR_PATH/img/user4.png" alt="Antonio">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="media-body">
                                                                    <h5 class="media-heading name">Jane Doe</h5>
                                                                    <p class="text"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i>Please check the status of</p>
                                                                    <span class="timestamp">Oct 2</span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="inbox-item clearfix">
                                                        <a href="#">
                                                            <div class="media">
                                                                <div class="media-left">
                                                                    <img class="media-object" src="~/YOUR_PATH/img/user5.png" alt="Antonio">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="media-body">
                                                                    <h5 class="media-heading name">John Simmons</h5>
                                                                    <p class="text"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i>I've fixed the problem :)</p>
                                                                    <span class="timestamp">Sep 12</span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="notification-footer">
                                                        <a href="#">View All Messages</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="notification-item general">
                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-bell"></i><span class="count">8</span>
                                                            <span class="circle"></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                    <li class="notification-header">
                                                        <em>You have 8 notifications</em>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-comment green-font"></i>
                                                                    <span class="text">New comment on the blog post</span>
                                                                    <span class="timestamp">1 minute ago</span>
                                                                </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-user green-font"></i>
                                                                    <span class="text">New registered user</span>
                                                                    <span class="timestamp">12 minutes ago</span>
                                                                </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-comment green-font"></i>
                                                                    <span class="text">New comment on the blog post</span>
                                                                    <span class="timestamp">18 minutes ago</span>
                                                                </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart red-font"></i>
                                                                    <span class="text">4 new sales order</span>
                                                                    <span class="timestamp">4 hours ago</span>
                                                                </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-edit yellow-font"></i>
                                                                    <span class="text">3 product reviews awaiting moderation</span>
                                                                    <span class="timestamp">1 day ago</span>
                                                                </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-comment green-font"></i>
                                                                    <span class="text">New comment on the blog post</span>
                                                                    <span class="timestamp">3 days ago</span>
                                                                </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-comment green-font"></i>
                                                                    <span class="text">New comment on the blog post</span>
                                                                    <span class="timestamp">Oct 15</span>
                                                                </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-warning red-font"></i>
                                                                    <span class="text red-font">Low disk space!</span>
                                                                    <span class="timestamp">Oct 11</span>
                                                                </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="notification-footer">
                                                        <a href="#">View All Notifications</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="logged-user">
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                    <img src="~/YOUR_PATH/img/user-avatar.png" alt="User Avatar" />
                                                    <span class="name">Stacy Rose</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                                                </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                                            <span class="text">Profile</span>
                                                        </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                                                            <span class="text">Settings</span>
                                                        </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
                                                            <span class="text">Logout</span>
                                                        </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- sidebar -->
        <div class="" style="width: 150px; top: 40px; position: absolute;">
            <div id="left-sidebar" class="left-sidebar ">
                <!-- main-nav -->
                <div class="sidebar-scroll">
                    <nav class="main-nav">
                        <ul class="main-menu">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i><span class="text">Dashboard</span>
                                        <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu open">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span class="text">Dashboard v1</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="~/YOUR_PATH/Pages/index-transparent.html"><span class="text">Dashboard v1 Transp.</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="~/YOUR_PATH/Pages/index-dashboard-v2.html"><span class="text">Dashboard v2</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="~/YOUR_PATH/Pages/index-dashboard-v2-transparent.html"><span class="text">Dashboard v2 Trans.</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="~/YOUR_PATH/Pages/index-dashboard-v3.html"><span class="text">Dashboard v3</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="~/YOUR_PATH/Pages/index-dashboard-v4.html"><span class="text">Dashboard v4 <span class="badge element-bg-color-blue">New</span></span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-navicon"></i><span class="text">Navigations <span class="badge element-bg-color-blue">New</span></span>
                                        <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu ">
                                    <li><a href="nav-default-fixed.html"><span class="text">Default Fixed Sidebar</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="nav-normal.html"><span class="text">Normal Sidebar</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-columns"></i><span class="text">Layouts <span class="badge element-bg-color-blue">New</span></span>
                                        <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu ">
                                    <li><a href="layout-collapsed.html"><span class="text">Collapsed Sidebar</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="layout-minified.html"><span class="text">Minified Sidebar</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="layout-ontop-navigation.html"><span class="text">On-Top Navigation</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-clipboard fa-fw"></i><span class="text">Pages</span>
                                        <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu ">
                                    <li><a href="page-profile.html"><span class="text">Profile</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-invoice.html"><span class="text">Invoice</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-knowledgebase.html"><span class="text">Knowledge Base</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-new-message.html"><span class="text">New Message</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-view-message.html"><span class="text">View Message</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-search-result.html"><span class="text">Search Result</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-submit-ticket.html"><span class="text">Submit Ticket</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-faq.html"><span class="text">FAQ</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-register.html"><span class="text">Register</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-register-transparent.html"><span class="text">Register Transparent</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-login.html"><span class="text">Login</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-login-transparent.html"><span class="text">Login Transparent</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-404.html"><span class="text">404</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-404-transparent.html"><span class="text">404 Transparent</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-blank.html"><span class="text">Blank Page</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="page-inbox.html"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span class="text">Inbox <span class="badge red-bg">32</span></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-file"></i><span class="text">File Manager</span>
                                        <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu ">
                                    <li><a href="page-file-manager.html"><span class="text">Default</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="page-file-manager-transparent.html"><span class="text">Transparent</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="page-projects.html"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i><span class="text">Projects</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="page-project-detail.html"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i><span class="text">Project Detail</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fw"></i><span class="text">Charts &amp; Statistics</span>
                                        <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu ">
                                    <li><a href="charts-statistics.html"><span class="text">Charts</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="charts-statistics-transparent.html"><span class="text">Charts Transparent</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="charts-statistics-interactive.html"><span class="text">Interactive Charts</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="charts-statistics-interactive-transparent.html"><span class="text">Interactive Charts Transparent</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="charts-statistics-real-time.html"><span class="text">Realtime Charts</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="charts-statistics-real-time-transparent.html"><span class="text">Realtime Charts Transparent</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="charts-d3charts.html"><span class="text">D3 Charts</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-edit fw"></i><span class="text">Forms</span>
                                        <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu ">
                                    <li><a href="form-inplace-editing.html"><span class="text">In-place Editing</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="form-elements.html"><span class="text">Form Elements</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="form-layouts.html"><span class="text">Form Layouts</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="form-bootstrap-elements.html"><span class="text">Bootstrap Elements</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="form-validations.html"><span class="text">Validation</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="form-file-upload.html"><span class="text">File Upload</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="form-text-editor.html"><span class="text">Text Editor</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-list-alt fw"></i><span class="text">UI Elements</span>
                                        <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu ">
                                    <li><a href="ui-elements-general.html"><span class="text">General Elements</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ui-elements-tabs.html"><span class="text">Tabs</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ui-elements-buttons.html"><span class="text">Buttons</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ui-elements-icons.html"><span class="text">Icons <span class="badge element-bg-color-blue">Updated</span></span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ui-elements-flash-message.html"><span class="text">Flash Message</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="widgets.html"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece fa-fw"></i><span class="text">Widgets</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-gears fw"></i><span class="text">Components</span>
                                        <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu ">
                                    <li><a href="components-wizard.html"><span class="text">Wizard (with validation)</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="components-calendar.html"><span class="text">Calendar</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="components-maps.html"><span class="text">Maps</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="components-maps-transparent.html"><span class="text">Maps Transparent</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="components-gallery.html"><span class="text">Gallery</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="components-tree-view.html"><span class="text">Tree View </span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="components-tree-view-transparent.html"><span class="text">Tree View Transparent</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-table fw"></i><span class="text">Tables</span>
                                        <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu ">
                                    <li><a href="tables-static-table.html"><span class="text">Static Table</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="tables-dynamic-table.html"><span class="text">Dynamic Table</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="typography.html"><i class="fa fa-font fa-fw"></i><span class="text">Typography</span></a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                                            <span class="text">Menu Lvl 1</span>
                                            <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                                        </a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle">
                                                    <span class="text">Menu Lvl 2</span>
                                                    <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                                                </a>
                                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">Menu Lvl 3</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Menu Lvl 3</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Menu Lvl 3</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                                    <span class="text">Menu Lvl 2</span>
                                                </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- mainbody -->
        <div style="padding-top: 35px;">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="mainbody" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

    </form> 
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/YOUR_PATH/Scripts/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/YOUR_PATH/Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/YOUR_PATH/Scripts/plugins/wizard/wizard.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/YOUR_PATH/Scripts/plugins/modernizr/modernizr.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/YOUR_PATH/Scripts/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/YOUR_PATH/Scripts/king-common.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/YOUR_PATH/Scripts/plugins/parsley-validation/parsley.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/YOUR_PATH/Scripts/king-components.js") %>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Content Page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Pages/MasterPages/main.Master" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="iconHub._default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server"></asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainbody" runat="server">

    <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
        <div id="main-content-wrapper" class="content-wrapper ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 ">
                    <ul class="breadcrumb">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Components</a></li>
                        <li class="active">Wizard</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 ">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="main-header">
                    <h2>Wizard</h2>
                    <em>wizard with validation</em>
                </div>
                <div class="main-content">
                    <div class="widget">
                        <div class="widget-header">
                            <h3><i class="fa fa-magic"></i> Wizard</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <div class="wizard-wrapper">
                                <div id="demo-wizard" class="wizard">
                                    <ul class="steps">
                                        <li data-target="#step1" class="active"><span class="badge badge-info">1</span>Account Type<span class="chevron"></span></li>
                                        <li data-target="#step2"><span class="badge">2</span>User Account<span class="chevron"></span></li>
                                        <li data-target="#step3"><span class="badge">3</span>Options<span class="chevron"></span></li>
                                        <li data-target="#step4" class="last"><span class="badge">4</span>Create Account</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="step-content">
                                    <div class="step-pane active" id="step1">
                                        <form id="form1" data-parsley-validate novalidate>
                                            <p>Choose your account type:</p>
                                            <label class="fancy-radio">
                                              <input type="radio" name="account-type" value="personal" required data-parsley-errors-container="#error-step1">
                                              <span><i></i>Personal</span>
                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="fancy-radio">
                                              <input type="radio" name="account-type" value="business">
                                              <span><i></i>Business</span>
                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="fancy-radio">
                                              <input type="radio" name="account-type" value="enterprise">
                                              <span><i></i>Enterprise</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <p id="error-step1"></p>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="step-pane" id="step2">
                                        <form id="form2" data-parsley-validate novalidate>
                                            <p>
                                                Please provide email, username and password
                                                <br />
                                                <em><small>Field marked * is required</small></em>
                                            </p>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="email">Email *</label>
                                                        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="password">Password *</label>
                                                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="password2">Repeat Password *</label>
                                                        <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" class="form-control" required data-parsley-equalto="#password" data-parsley-equalto-message="Password doesn't match.">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="step-pane" id="step3">
                                        <form id="form3" data-parsley-validate novalidate>
                                            <label class="fancy-checkbox">
                                              <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter">
                                              <span>Subscribe to monthly newsletter</span>
                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="fancy-checkbox">
                                              <input type="checkbox" name="terms">
                                              <span>I accept the <a href="#">Terms &amp; Agreements</a></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="step-pane" id="step4">
                                        <p class="lead"><i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success"></i> All is well! Click "Create My Account" to complete.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="actions">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-prev"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Prev</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-next">Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer class="footer">&copy; 2017</footer>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thank you that was very useful critic on the code, I have done the changes, my Nabar collapse and menu cordian still working as previously but the Wizard is still not working.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion? I am really stuck

Comment: Three possible work around from my side. 1st check all your .js files are getting loaded or not by either going to page source or in the browser dev tool's network tab. 2nd check any error is coming when you clicking on the wizard next button if yes then dig into that. 3rd check your html elements are complete as per wizard and having respective css classes applied